# Cannot access the referenced collection data through Nested JSON object in React MERN

Tags: reactjs, json, mern

I'm trying to send get the referenced collection's data in the front end and display both collections. I can display the project data but I can't display the client's company data.

**Project model class - backend**
I have referenced the company collection here

```
const projectSchema = new Schema(
  {
    projectName: { type: String, required: true },
    projectCategory: { type: String, required: true },
    clientCompanyID: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Company",
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Project = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);

module.exports = Project;
```

**Project controller - backend**
I am sending the project data and company name and company owner here.

```
//api/projects/
exports.readAllProjectsController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const projects = await Project.find({}).populate({
      path: "clientCompanyID",
      select: ["companyName", "companyOwner"],
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      projects,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(" readAllProjectsController error ", err);
    res.status(500).json({
      errorMsg: "Server Error. Please Try again",
    });
  }
};
```

**JSON output**

```
{
            "_id": "6118f2ade284295fd0091eb7",
            "projectName": "Project SAS",
            "projectCategory": "Mobile App",
            "clientCompanyID": {
                "_id": "610d1d18aa4a2c2e141f7a9a",
                "companyName": "APIIT",
                "companyOwner": "Sam Smith"
            },
            "createdAt": "2021-08-15T10:55:41.182Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-15T10:55:41.182Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
```

**Project.js** I'm getting the project details and showing them on a card view. AllprojectCard is the individual card. I'm passing data into that. don't mind the search function.

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProjects());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const { projects } = useSelector((state) => state.projects);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const filteredProjects = projects.filter((project) => {
    return project.projectName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
  });

return (
          <div className="row">
            {filteredProjects?.length > 0 ? (
              <div className="card-deck">
                {filteredProjects.map((projects) => (
                  <AllProjectsCard
                    key={projects._id}
                    projects={projects}
                  ></AllProjectsCard>
                ))}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                {" "}
                <i>No Projects Found.</i>{" "}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>);
```

**AllProjectCard.js**

```
const AllProjectsCard = ({ projects }) => {
 
  return (
    <div className="col-md-4 my-3">
      <Link to={`/project/${projects._id}`}>
        <div className="card h-100">
          <h5 className="cardTitle">{projects.projectName}</h5>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-8">
              <div className="card_text">
                <div className="cardtextBold">
                  Company : <div className="d-inline cardtextNormal"> 
                 {projects.clientCompanyID.companyName}
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div className="cardtextBold">
                  Lead :{" "}
                  <div className="d-inline cardtextNormal ">Naveen Perera</div>
                </div>
                <div className="cardtextBold">
                  Category :{" "}
                  <div className="d-inline cardtextNormal">
                    {projects.projectCategory}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
export default AllProjectsCard;
```

I can access the name of the project by `{project.projectName}` but I cannot access company name by `{projects.clientCompanyID.companyName}`
it says `companyName is not defined`.

Comment: its come in loop so may be some object does not have company  define so try adding a check like " {(projects.clientCompanyID)?projects.clientCompanyID.companyName:'N/A'} "

Comment: thank you very much. It worked!!!! yes, there was an object without the company defined. @huzaifaqidwai